# React navigation stack navigator disable go back ability

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to disable ability to go back

I have a functional component

```
    export default function App(){

createHomeStackNavigator = () =>
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
                        headerShown: false
    }}>
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            children={createHomeTabNavigator}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
return(
    <NavigationContainer>
        {createHomeStackNavigator()}
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

When user goes to Home, its onclick on Login component then he cant go back to the login by any swipe on ios, back button on Android and other ways

Comment: you need to use switchNavigator for that, it achives the purpose that u wnat  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/switch-navigator/

Comment: @AhmedKhattab Im using 5.x

Comment: did you use backHandler https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/backhandler

Comment: no, i'll try use it but im looking for something like set index:0 to my stack navigator like in react-navigator version 4.x

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use `navigation.reset();`

Answer (score 0):

When you set up `StackNavigatorParams` set `redirect` param for `Login` screen

```
import { createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack";

export type StackNavigatorParams = {
    Home: undefined;
    Settings: undefined;
    Login: { redirect: keyof StackNavigatorParams } | undefined;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<StackNavigatorParams>();
```

Now inside `loginHandler` when the user press `LoginButton` you set the `redirect` param. When stack navigator ever detects redirecting to "Login" page it will redirect the user to the "Home" screen

```
export default function Login({ navigation, route }: LoginProps): ReactElement {
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
        username: "username",
        password: ""
    });

    const redirect = route.params?.redirect;

    const login = async () => {
        const { username, password } = formState;
        try {
            await yourSignInFunction(username, password);
            // "replace", if we go back, we go back to "Home" not to Login
            redirect ? navigation.replace(redirect) : navigation.navigate("Home");
        } catch (e) {}
    };

    return <Button onPress={login} />;
}
```